# How can you find Patrick Flandrin's source codes in his TF publication?

Tags: time-series, research

I am reading his publication **Elements de Traitement du Signal** but I cannot find his sources codes such as files *change.m, sousech.m, ...*

Some his TF codes are [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/stat_test.html), and probably, he is about these codes too [here](http://tfd.sourceforge.net/) partially. 
His homepage [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/essai_entree2.html).
He speaks French but I do not know about his English proficiency. 
I contacted him unsuccessfully.

Some versions of his publication

- [0.89](http://www.esiee.fr/~bercherj/New/polys/g_signal.pdf) with colloboration
- here references to [his files](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/CoursM2SC_1112.pdf)

Comment: The suggestion that Flandrin does not speak English is... refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the codes are [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/enseignement.html) about *enseignement* which is Teaching, not Contributions as Google Translate proposes.
However,  I cannot find exactly the file `sousech.m` which can be French. 
I think *change.m* is nowadays *mean_change.m*.
*AR_change.m* is also missing.

I got now also answer from the author. 
He said that most codes are in the page above. 
The author is fluent in English.

I also asked for the missing files. 
He answered

- sousech.m is some extra file
- AR_change.m have changed into ARMA_change.m

This work is his old stuff so he could not provide exact answers, he said.
Still, the challenge is when some papers refer to his paper, I should be able to reproduce the effects. 
So better answer is also welcome who knows more about this.

About time-frequency stuff, he says that rather go to [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/patrick.flandrin/software2.html).

Comment: Google Translate proposes "education teaching instruction schoolteaching elaboration" (all pretty accurate except "elaboration"), not "contributions".

Comment: @Did In which locale are you using Google Translate? I used in site Google Translate which takes into account also words nearby.  I think this confused the system.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/enseignement

Comment: I used this https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fperso.ens-lyon.fr%2Fpatrick.flandrin%2Fessai_entree2_eng.html